# Get next date and day

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table to which i dynamically add rows. The number of days is equal to the date difference of the dates inserted by user. On the dynamic rows i want to add three fields. The first two are date and day filed. For that I need to know the next date and the corresponding day. For example user enters 10-2-2012. I need to insert The next dates like 17-2-2012,18-2-2012... and corresponding days like Wednesday, Thursday..etc 
I have used the following function to get next date

```
function getTomorrow(d,offset)
{
    if (!offset)
    {
       offset = 1
    }
    return new Date(new Date().setDate(d.getDate() + offset));
}
```

But it shows error 16-2-2012 has no getDate() function. Am not able to find next date and the corresponding day. Is there any way to get it?

Comment: Please [provide a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net) of your problem. What is `d`? How do you call `getTomorrow`?

Comment: d is the date in dd-mm-yy format

Comment: In case you find yourself doing a lot of date manipulation in the future, I can't recommend  [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) enough. Adding days to an existing date is just a matter of  `moment().add('d', 1);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert the string `d` into a `Date` object:

```js
function getTomorrow(d,offset){
    if (!offset){
        offset = 1;
    }
    if(typeof(d) === "string"){
        var t = d.split("-"); /* splits dd-mm-year */
        d = new Date(t[2],t[1] - 1, t[0]);
    //  d = new Date(t[2],t[1] - 1, t[0] + 2000); /* for dd-mm-yy */
    }
    return new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + offset));
}    

document.write(getTomorrow('16-02-2012',20) + ' test');

var k = getTomorrow('16-02-2012',1);
var myTime = k.getDate()+'-'+(k.getMonth()+1)+'-'+k.getFullYear();

alert(myTime);
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hLqSQ/1/embedded/result/). See also http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp.

Comment: Thanx it works fine. but I need the date and day separately. And Date in the format dd-mm-yy. Can I extract it from the string

Comment: If you use `dd-mm-yy`, you have to adjust `d = new Date(t[2],t[1],t[0] + 2000);`. What do you mean, you need *date* and *day* separately? You could use `.getDate()` on the returned object: `getTomorrow('16-02-2012',1).getDate()`.

Comment: In JS, months are zero-based so use `new Date(t[2],t[1] - 1,t[0])`.

Comment: @Zeta if i do getTomorrow('16-02-2012',1).getDate() then the value returned is only 17. What I need is 17-2-2012

Comment: Sorry man, in your function the month is always fixed as February. Cant change it to the one provide.

Comment: @Cyphon: I fixed the function. Use `var k = getTomorrow('16-02-2012',1); var myTime = k.getDate()+'-'+(k.getMonth()+1)+'-'+k.getFullYear();` to the right format. Note that you have to adjust months/days with only one digit.

Answer (score 3):

```
 var d=new Date();                 

d.setTime((d.getTime() + 86400 * 1000*1)); 

document.write(d);

document.write(d.getDay()+"-"+parseInt(d.getMonth()+1)+"-"+d.getFullYear());
```

if you need to know the date of day after tommorow , just change 1000*1 to 1000*2.

Answer (score -1):

i giving a example

```
var year = 2010, month = 9, day = 14;
    // The value of `meses`
    var offset = 1; // Tomorow

    var future_date = new Date(year, month , day+offset);

    console.log(future_date);
```